# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Not working xDebug in PhpStorm. Waiting for connection all time.

My configuration

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.dump.REQUEST = *
xdebug.dump.SESSION = *
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:/openserver/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:/openserver/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
```

[image: configuration in PHPStorm]

[image: error]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: are you running php-fpm by any chance ? it ships with default port 9000 (like xdebug) and if the php-fpm was started before phpstorm, it would cause issues. Look at the xdebug log to see what happens in there.

Comment: temp\xdebug is empty

Comment: so ... either Xdebug is misconfigured (as per BettleJuice answer below), or it does not have permission to write to the directory/file where it wants to write its log. Same for Apache logs. Remember, if you change any of apache's or php's configurations, restart the processes (including and very importantly php-fpm if you are using that).

Answer (score 1):

You can try these one at a time and retest, or do them all at once. You may need to restart PHPStorm -- or at the very least restart the debugging session -- between tests

1. In PHPStorm settings,, change the debug port from 9000 to a random number, and make the same change in `php.ini` to avoid a possible port conflict with another application.
2. Make sure that the `php.ini` file that has your XDebug settings is the file actually loaded. Execute `phpinfo();` It will print a lot of info about your PHP installation. Find `Loaded Configuration File` and make sure it corresponds to the file you posted.
3. Make sure that `"c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6-x64/ext/php_xdebug.dll"` is a valid path. This is where PHP looks for the debugger extension.
4. In the `[Xdebug]` section you posted, add `xdebug.remote_autostart=1`
5. In your `php.ini`, set `display_startup_errors = On`, restart Apache/PHP and look for errors in the logs

Comment: I did all this actions but it is not working with the same problem, in php log nothing, in apache log only writing, temp\xdebug is empty                                                                                                                                             _[Sat Jul 16 11:52:37.707858 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5048:tid 512] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jul 16 11:52:37.723870 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5048:tid 512] AH00354: Child: Starting 32 worker threads._